# How do you use SOURCE in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Using SOURCE at the command prompt works fine. However, I came across a sample database sql file that contains source statements to load the data into the tables it has created. Here is the SQL file (from https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db):

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS employees;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS employees;
USE employees;

SELECT 'CREATING DATABASE STRUCTURE' as 'INFO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dept_emp,
                     dept_manager,
                     titles,
                     salaries, 
                     employees, 
                     departments;

/*!50503 set default_storage_engine = InnoDB */;
/*!50503 select CONCAT('storage engine: ', @@default_storage_engine) as INFO */;

CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

CREATE TABLE departments (
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    dept_name   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dept_no),
    UNIQUE  KEY (dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE dept_manager (
   emp_no       INT             NOT NULL,
   dept_no      CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
   from_date    DATE            NOT NULL,
   to_date      DATE            NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees (emp_no)    ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
); 

CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees   (emp_no)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
);

CREATE TABLE titles (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    title       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,title, from_date)
) 
; 

CREATE TABLE salaries (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    salary      INT             NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, from_date)
) 
; 

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dept_emp_latest_date AS
    SELECT emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS from_date, MAX(to_date) AS to_date
    FROM dept_emp
    GROUP BY emp_no;

# shows only the current department for each employee
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW current_dept_emp AS
    SELECT l.emp_no, dept_no, l.from_date, l.to_date
    FROM dept_emp d
        INNER JOIN dept_emp_latest_date l
        ON d.emp_no=l.emp_no AND d.from_date=l.from_date AND l.to_date = d.to_date;

flush /*!50503 binary */ logs;

SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;

source show_elapsed.sql ;
```

As you can see, the last few commands are SOURCE. However, when it hits these source command it fails with a 1064 syntax error. I've tried this approach with other source files that I know will work at the command shell level, but they fail when in a query.

I find this puzzling because (a) there's no information as to why this fails, and (b) it seems inconceivable that this well-known sample database on GitHub would have such a syntax error.

Comment: Which statement gets the 1064?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: And show us the command used to run that file.

Comment: 1064 was when I tried use HeidiSQL to run the commands. I'm using MySQL version 8.x.x. In the command prompt, the last one I did was:
mysql> source D:/Dropbox/test/employees.sql

Comment: 1064 shows precisely where the error is.  Show us the full statement.  If Heidi won't provide the detail, use the 'mysql' commandline tool instead.

Answer (score 4):

> when it hits these source command it fails

Unfortunately, you don't specify what "it" is that hits and fails. Apparently, it's some sort of a UI that you use to run the script.

`source` is a [MySQL command line client command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html), not an SQL statement, so if you use any other interface to execute the script it may not understand `source` and pass it to the database server, which obviously won't recognize it as a valid statement either, resulting in a syntax error.

Comment: I've tried with admins tools like HeidiSQL and DBeaver, but also tried using the command prompt with the command SOURCE, followed by the path to the employees.sql file. It does the DDL part fine, creating all the tables, but still gives an error when it comes to these source commands.

Comment: Did you run `mysql` from the directory where the .dump files are?

Comment: No, I did not, as I would need to set up an environment path for that. Perhaps this was the issue then.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do the load this way:

```
cd D:\Dropbox\test
mysql -u user -p < employees.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The *.dump files referenced by the source command need to be replaced with a *.sql extension. I modified this script using *.sql instead of *.dump file and it worked like a charm on an Ubuntu VM.